# How to make field mandatory based on another field without javascript?

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads, inputfield

I am trying to achieve a functionality where GST no field should be mandatory when IST flag is set to yes.Below piece of code didnt work for me . Also I cannot use Javascript for some reason

```
 <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <!--<apex:image id="theImage8" value="{!$Resource.StarIcon}" width="5px" height="5px" alt="Description of image here"/>-->
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!Lead.Is_GST__c}" required="true" id="IsGSTID"  styleClass="slds-input">
                                    </apex:inputField>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element" id="ProGSTRegisNo">

                                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                            <!--<apex:image id="theImage11" value="{!$Resource.StarIcon}" width="5px" height="5px" alt="Description of image here"/>-->
                                            <label>Provisional GST Registration Number</label>
                                            <apex:inputField required="{!IF(Lead.Is_GST__c = 'Yes',True,False)}" value="{!Lead.Provisional_GST_Registration_Number__c}" id="GSTRegistrationNumberId" styleClass="slds-input" />
                                      <div id="err51"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="err13"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess adding actionSupport is not enough, you also need to rerender your input.
The solution that should work is provided here by Glyn Anderson: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008y1ZIAQ

Comment: Thank you @Andrei . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do at this point is add apex:actionSupport:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Lead.Is_GST__c}" required="true" id="IsGSTID"  styleClass="slds-input">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" />
</apex:inputField>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but validation is still not working. It allows me to save the lead form even if i keep GST number field blank and IsGST flag is set to true.